# passing pointer to std::function<void()>

Tags: c++

what is the best practice to avoid UB when passing a pointer to `std::function<void()>` in `[]` ?

will the `cls_ptr` always be valid in the `second_on_finish` if the object isnt deleted?

this is the current code:

```
void Foo()
{
    SomeClass* cls_ptr = GetPointerToClass();

    std::function<void()> first_on_finish = [cls_ptr]() {

        if (some_argument == true)
        {
            std::function<void()> second_on_finish = [cls_ptr]() {
                //cls_ptr is always valid here?
            };
            run_in_a_few_seconds(second_on_finish);
        }

    };

    run_in_a_few_seconds(first_on_finish);
}
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr` might extend lifetime or allow to test pointer validity.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's also a good way to get a circular reference you may not notice, if you forget the weak_ptr part :D

Comment: `[cls_ptr]` means capturing (local variable) `cls_ptr` _by value_. It's not a problem that the local variable goes out of scope before lambda is called. (Capturing it _by reference_ i.e. `[&cls_ptr]` would be a problem.) However, the actual problem is (IMHO) the life-time of the pointe**e** of `cls_ptr`...

Comment: `GetPointerToClass` should return a pointer to object with infinitive lifetime, this is what I would expect from function with such name. If this is not the case (this is only reason you can have UB), then consider renaming function. To fix it you have make sure that the life time of the pointed object is longer then lifetime of the lambda which captures the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the cls_ptr always be valid in the second_on_finish if the object isnt deleted

If you mean that `cls_ptr`wasn't destroyed by that time - the answer is **yes**. Pointer is captured by value (not the object it points to) so untill object is destroyed at that address - you can deference it.

Comment: Especially, in combination with lambdas, raw pointers are good for becoming dangling. Hence, the comment of Jarod42 (about `std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr`) is worth to be elaborated.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it should be used with care. However we don't know the context - maybe is function exists only within the more narrow scope that the object, etc.